# How to extract text from element where the parent element is having attribute style="display:none" using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: This Image Shows my Html Source]

I want to extract Phone number from this div. This div has style="display:none"
So I can not access the children of this div. Please help me out in getting the phone number from the div.

I guess We need to change that display:none; to visibility:visible. How can I do this in Python Selenuim

**Edit**

I have tried the code below, as suggested in the first answer but it throws the following error:

```
email_div = browser.find_element_by_class_name("returnemail")
email_div_contents = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML', email_div)
telephone = email_div_contents.find_element_by_class_name('reply-tel-number').get_attribute('textContent')
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute
>   'find_element_by_class_name

'

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Since you haven't managed to write *any* code pertinent to the problem, you really need to back up and work on the basic tools first.

Comment: Hi, you should have added a comment into my answer instead of editing the question with the code I posted, otherwise I have no way of knowing!

Comment: See my updated answer use: email_div_contents = email_div.get_attribute('innerHTML') instead of browser.execute etc..

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation `execute_script()` returns:

> The command's JSON response loaded into a dictionary object.

Hence, moving forward when you attempted to invoke `find_element_by_class_name()` method on the *dictionary object* as follows:

```
email_div_contents.find_element_by_class_name('reply-tel-number').get_attribute('textContent')
```

The following error is raised:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

---

To remove the attribute **style="display:none"** from the desired element and extract the *phone number* you can use the following solution:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='returnemail js-only']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
tel_number = element.find_element_by_xpath("./aside/ul//li//p[@class='reply-tel-number']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: `element.get_attribute()` work on visible and invisible element, thus no need to modify the CSS to make the element visible to change the original display logical of the page, in some case, this will change the page layout, at least it's not recommend way.

Answer (score -2):

Your code has incorrect place:

```
email_div = browser.find_element_by_class_name("returnemail")
email_div_contents = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML', email_div)
email_div_contents.find_element_by_class_name()
```

`email_div_contents` is a string represents the HTML code of the `email_div`, not a web element,
 You can't call `find_element_by_class_name()` on a string.

That's why you got error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

You can always call `get_attribute()` to fetch attribute value on visible and invisible element.

To get the text content of invisible element you can use `get_attribute('innerText')`.

```
phone_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.returnemail .reply-tel-number")
                     .get_attribute('innerText')
```

Actually, `element.text` call `element.get_attribute('innerText')` inside, but `element.text` will respect user experience:  If user can't see the element from page, `element.text` will return empty string as user see. (Even `element.get_attribute('innerText')` return non-empty string)

```
   @property
   text:
     if ( element is visible ):
        return element.get_attribute('innerText')

     else:
        return ''
```

Comment: `execute_script()` doesn't returns a `string` but returns **The command's JSON response loaded into a dictionary object.**. So `email_div_contents` is never a _string_. Please refer the API Docs for details.